# C: How to search for the last occurrence of a character as efficiently as possible

Tags: c

I need to find the last occurrence (if any) of a character as fast a possible. The **total length** of the string is **unknown**, but the **maximum length** is known.

Consider the following example:

```
char cwd[PATH_MAX]; // this can have up to PATH_MAX chars (e.g. 1024)
```

The string could like `/Users/leon/Downloads/program_a/bin64` and I would like to find the last `/`, so that I can return `/bin64`.

My current solution:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char cwd[PATH_MAX];
    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) == NULL)
    {
        perror("getcwd() error");
    }

    char *pch;
    char *last = cwd;
    pch = strchr(cwd, '/');
    while (1)
    {
        pch = strchr(pch + 1, '/');
        if (pch == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
        last = pch;
    }


    printf("%s\n", last);
    return 0;
}
```

This works but it has to traverse the full path all the time. Is there a better method to do this?

Comment: One simple improvement is to traverse from the *end* instead of the beginning. And use the standard [`strrchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr) function instead.

Comment: But I don't know where the string is terminated. I only know PATH_MAX which is much bigger than the path itself in most cases.

Comment: Looks like the raw linux syscall will tell you the length (unlike the POSIX API). Then you can use `memrchr` (also nonstandard, but what can you do when the standards suck?).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, how do you think `strrchr` is implemented? It's impossible to start at the end, because the end of a zero-terminated is not known in advance. I agree that using `strrchr` would be an improvement, but only because I think that using standard functions is better then reinventing the wheel and because I assume the standard library routine is likely better optimized than this native C implementation. Not because it's traversing from the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you consider to keep track of the current directory somewhere in you shell?

Normally you would need to have some kind of builtin implementation of `cd`. 
Ideally you would just update the current folder (stored in some variable somewhere) and update it everytime `cd` is called.

Of course you need to handle special cases like `cd ..` or `cd ~`. But at the end of the day, this should be much more efficient.

Comment: This seems like a nice approach. I will definitely implement this. But in some case I still would need a fast way to find to current folder, e.g. first run oder `cd ..`.

Answer (score -1):

Simplified version:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char cwd[PATH_MAX] = {0,};
    char *last = NULL;
    unsigned pos;

    if (!getcwd(cwd, sizeof cwd) )
    {
        perror("getcwd() error");
    }

    for(pos=0; cwd[pos]; pos++) {
        if (cwd[pos] == '/') last = cwd+pos;
        }

    printf("%s\n", last? last: "Null" );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `perror()` does not exit, so after diagnosing failure, the code blunders on using the uninitialized array.

Comment: I wanted to keep as much of the original logic intact. (Also tested with a smaller buffer size, and the loop won't find a `'/'` ;-)